# dividing bootstrap grid into sub grid

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap in my web application targeting all devices. I have divided the main row into three column(ex. second row ). Now I want to treat each divided column to another set of 12 columns each (like third row) and divide it. while dividing the main column to sub column, do I need to consider the screen size here ? If so, than what would be grid specification for it cause here generated column would be of different column width? or I have to use table tag for such purpose.

[image]

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you want to achieve and why it's not working ? Here is a link that you might find very usefull : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: I am trying to divide generated  sub column into set of columns. like in above figure, can we treat the third row's each column as 12 column  and than divide them  as per requirement?

Answer (score 9):

Bootstrap grid is great to handle nesting. & also follow same responsive design pattern as you would expect from the parent.

In order to nest a child in bootstrap. Use row inside column.

e.g.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <!-- Creating a child here and divide col-8 into 2 parts. -->
      <div class="row">

        <!-- Note that for bootstrap all the rows are always 12 columns --> 
        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that bootstrap treats all the rows as 12 columns.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I think @kishanio's answer is more then self explanatory - I decided to break this down for you further.

[image]

Also i think this code will give you what you are describing above

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row"> **this one tricky? naaa**
    <div class="col-md-4"> **split page in 3's** Whats 1/3rd of 12 .. 12:3 = 4
        <div class="row"> **only use first 3rd of page**
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    </div>
</div>
```